# Hibernate Transformers.aliasToBean populate primary fields

Tags: sql-server, hql

I am trying to get list of `Tbcompany` table using `Transformers.aliasToBean` with 2 primary key fields.

I am using SQL SERVER and Hibernate 3.2.4.

My table has 2 primary fields.

Tbcompany.class

```
public class Tbcompany {

    private TbcompanyId id;
    private String hcompanycode;


    public TbcompanyId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(TbcompanyId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getHcompanycode() {
        return hcompanycode;
    }

    public void setHcompanycode(String hcompanycode) {
        this.hcompanycode = hcompanycode;
    }
}
```

And inside TbcompanyId.class :

```
public class TbcompanyId
    implements Serializable
{

private String companycode;
private String companyname;

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof TbcompanyId)) {
        return false;
    }
    TbcompanyId other = ((TbcompanyId) o);
    if (this.companycode == null) {
        if (other.companycode!= null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        if (!this.companycode.equals(other.companycode)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (this.companyname == null) {
        if (other.companyname!= null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        if (!this.companyname.equals(other.companyname)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public int hashCode() {
    int rtn = 17;
    rtn = (rtn* 37);
    if (this.companycode!= null) {
        rtn = (rtn + this.companycode.hashCode());
    }
    rtn = (rtn* 37);
    if (this.companyname!= null) {
        rtn = (rtn + this.companyname.hashCode());
    }
    return rtn;
}

public String getCompanycode() {
    return companycode;
}

public void setCompanycode(String companycode) {
    this.companycode = companycode;
}

public String getCompanyname() {
    return companyname;
}

public void setCompanyname(String companyname) {
    this.companyname = companyname;
}
```

I want to create a form and use Transformers.aliasToBean to populate the form .

This query :

```
Query q;
q = session.createQuery("SELECT a.id.companycode as companycode,a.id.companyname as companyname,a.hcompanycode as hcompanycode FROM Tbcompany a");
q.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Tbcompany.class));
list = q.list();
```

gives me an error of :

```
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for companycode on class com.loansdb.data.Tbcompany
```

While this query :

```
Query q;
q = session.createQuery("SELECT a.id.companycode,a.id.companyname,a.hcompanycode as hcompanycode FROM 
Tbcompany a");
q.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Tbcompany.class));
list = q.list();
```

gives me this error :

```
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for 0 on class com.loansdb.data.Tbcompany
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `aliasToBean` transformer use the **name** of the SQL columns returned and try to find a field with the **same name** on the class target that have a `set` method created.

So, your query returns a `a.id.`**companycode**:

```
SELECT a.id.companycode as companycode,a.id.companyname as companyname,a.hcompanycode as hcompanycode FROM Tbcompany a
```

The error said:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for companycode on class com.loansdb.data.Tbcompany
```

And your `Tbcompany` class does not have a setter to **companycode**.

So, to correct your `Tbcompany` class and looking your query, seems to me that the class it's something like:

```
public class Tbcompany {

    private String companycode;
    private String companycode;
    private String companyname;

    public String setCompanycode(String companycode) {
        this.companycode = companycode;
    }

    // create the constructor, getters and setters
}
```